# How do I swim underwater in GTA San Andreas for iOS?

Tags: ios, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I am on my iPad, and I can't seem to able to dive and then swim underwater. My character just pops back up. Does anyone know how to swim on this version of the game? I need to do this for a mission.

Answer (score 2):

take your left thumb off the movement controls after you dive and press swim. its u touching the left side that makes u go up